# Why use requestFileSystem?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, fileapi

What is the point of requestFileSystem if I can just use resolveLocalFileSystemURI to get the root directory?

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileSystem